# How to install a mobile-only Android app on an Android tablet?

Tags: google-play-store, tablet

How to install a mobile-only Android app on an Android tablet? By "mobile-only", I meant the app has only released a mobile version and no tablet version. For example, [DoorDash](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dd.doordash) is one such app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of the DoorDash app I would say the developers are simply too stupid to understand that in the Android eco system there are still tablets without cellular.

From my perspective the only functionality of this app which requires a mobile is the function to make phone calls from within the app (Android [`CALL_PHONE` permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CALL_PHONE)). I am not familiar with DoorDash but I would assume that is is not a fundamental problem if you just want to order something.

If Google Play Store refuses app installation then you can still use one of the free APK sources like https://ApkMirror.com or https://ApkPure.com (as long as you trust those sites).

Both provide the DoorDash app and it can be installed on a non-cellular tablet without problem.

- https://apkpure.com/de/doordash-food-delivery/com.dd.doordash
- https://www.apkmirror.com/?post_type=app_release&searchtype=apk&s=com.dd.doordash

Comment: Thanks, glad to see the answer is this simple. I'll try to get in touch with some DoorDash developers to get this $1M easy bug fixed...

Answer (score 0):

You can try finding an APK for the app online. If it's not on the Play Store, it probably won't work with your device. Normally, apps are available for both  phone and tablet, whether or not it's made for mobile. Correct me if I am wrong.